# HSQLDB Table not found in statement with Spring 3 jUnit test

Tags: java, sql, spring, junit, hsqldb

I have two jUnit test classes, one for testing my `ItemService` class, the other for testing my `LocationService` class.  When I run an `ItemService` test, it passes.  When I run a `LocationService` test, it fails with:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM locations]
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)

I have a schema file being loaded into the database, and the first table it creates is the one `ItemService` uses.  Maybe the `locations` table that my `LocationService` test uses does not get created, even though it's in the same schema file?

This is in my test-context.xml file:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database
    id="myTestDB"
    type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script
        location="classpath:/test-ddl.sql" />
    <jdbc:script
        location="classpath:/test-data.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<bean
    id="dataSourceTest"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property
        name="driverClassName"
        value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property
        name="url"
        value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myTestDB" />
    <property
        name="username"
        value="sa" />
    <property
        name="password"
        value="" />
</bean>
```

I don't understand why one test passes with no errors thrown about the `items` table being missing, while another test fails because `locations` doesn't exist in the database.  I saw other posts about using HSQLDB and Hibernate, but I'm not using Hibernate.  These are the tables I'm creating in the test-ddl.sql file:

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE "ITEMS" (
    "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "LOCATION_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "ITEM_TYPE_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE MEMORY TABLE "ITEM_TYPES" (
    "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "ICON_CLASS" VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE CACHED TABLE "LOCATIONS" (
    "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    "NAME" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "PHOTO" LONGVARBINARY,
    "PHOTO_CONTENT_TYPE" VARCHAR(60),
    "PHOTO_WIDTH" INTEGER,
    "PHOTO_HEIGHT" INTEGER
);
```

I also set some `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` constraints in the schema after the table creation statements, but surely it would tell me if it couldn't create something.  I'm using the HSQLDB 1.8.1.3 JAR.  Why can I not query `locations` but I can query `items`?

**Edit:** thought based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121128/problems-with-escaping-table-and-field-names-in-derby-and-hsqldb) there might be a case-sensitivity issue, but even trying to SELECT from the `LOCATIONS` table fails:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LOCATIONS]

**Edit:** my magical working `ItemService` test:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
public class ItemServiceTest {
    private EmbeddedDatabase _db;
    private ItemService _svc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        _db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .setName("myTestDB").build();
        assertThat(_db, is(notNullValue()));
        _svc = new ItemService();
        _svc.setDataSource(_db);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        _db.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCount() {
        assertThat(_svc.getCount(), is(not(0)));
    }
}
```

My failing `LocationService` test is the exact same, but with `LocationService` instead of `ItemService`.  The `getCount()` method shows up in both `LocationService` and in `ItemService`:

```
public int getCount() {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    return _jdbcTmpl.queryForInt(sql, (Map<String, Object>)null);
}
```

The `TABLE_NAME` varies between `ItemService`:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ITEMS";
```

and `LocationService`:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "LOCATIONS";
```

Both `ItemService` and `LocationService` have the following:

```
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate _jdbcTmpl;

@Resource(name = "dataSource")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    _jdbcTmpl = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

**Edit:** new twist to the problem.  In my `LocationService` test, I had some other test methods that weren't fleshed out yet, e.g.

```
@Test
public void testFind() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

While in my `ItemService` test, the only `@Test` method was the `testGetCount` that passes.  When I add the above `testFind` to the `ItemService` test class, suddenly its `testGetCount` fails just like in my `LocationService` test class:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITEMS]

**Edit:** stepping through with the debugger when I'm not using `static` `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass` methods (i.e., when the test couldn't find the table), I noticed the following console output:

> Apr 10, 2012 10:22:44 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory initDatabase
>   INFO: Creating embedded database 'myTestDB'
>   Apr 10, 2012 10:22:44 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator executeSqlScript
>   INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [test-ddl.sql]
>   Apr 10, 2012 10:22:44 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator executeSqlScript
>   INFO: Done executing SQL script from class path resource [test-ddl.sql] in 30 ms.
>   Apr 10, 2012 10:22:44 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator executeSqlScript
>   INFO: Executing SQL script from class path resource [test-data.sql]
>   Apr 10, 2012 10:22:44 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator executeSqlScript
>   INFO: Done executing SQL script from class path resource [test-data.sql] in 46 ms.
>   Apr 10, 2012 10:22:55 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory initDatabase
>   INFO: Creating embedded database 'myTestDB'
>   Apr 10, 2012 10:23:08 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory initDatabase
>   INFO: Creating embedded database 'myTestDB'

So it looks like it sets up the database and runs my create-tables and populate-tables 
scripts initially, then any time after that when I reinitialize `_db`, the scripts don't get run again.  So the tables don't exist for subsequent test methods.  So if I could find a way to force Spring to re-run those scripts each time, I could go back to using `@Before` and `@After` with instance methods for my setup and teardown methods.

Comment: Can you show us the code that execute the query? (Your jUnit test and your Service class codes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`addScript`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html#addScript%28java.lang.String%29) was the answer.  I removed the initialization scripts from my test-context.xml, so my `jdbc:embedded-database` tag looks like:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database
    id="myTestDB"
    type="HSQL" />
```

In my `setUp()` method in my test class, I changed my `_db` initialization to:

```
_db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
    .setName("myTestDB").addScript("test-ddl.sql")
    .addScript("test-data.sql").build();
```

My `setUp` and `tearDown` methods remain instance methods, annotated with `@Before` and `@After`, respectively.  Using the debugger, I see console output for each test saying my two initialization SQL scripts were run, so the tables exist for each test.

Answer (score 1):

`@BeforeClass` and `static`!  I changed my test classes to have the following setup and teardown methods:

```
private static EmbeddedDatabase _db;
private static LocationService _svc;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    _db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
        .setName("myTestDB").build();
    assertThat(_db, is(notNullValue()));
    _svc = new LocationService();
    _svc.setDataSource(_db);
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
    _db.shutdown();
}
```

Now both my `ItemService` and `LocationService` tests are passing, even with other tests in the class.  The "table not found in statement" error I was getting before seems a little bizarre in response to before-every-test setup versus [before-all-tests-in-class](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#organize_3) setup...