# how can solve these trouble when i convert form apathy server DB to derby DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, derby, executable-jar

because i'm convert my concoction DB to derby in netbeans
all statement happen error in it.

**the error is it**

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: table or view does not exist.
```

to solve problem must be change in all attribute and tables name
by Place it between brackets

**for example**

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM   loges ");
```

not run its syntax error
must change to

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM   \"loges\" ");
```

Then it works properly
doing this very hard,i have 137 query statement contain a lot
of tables and attribute names.

i'm doing this change because extract my project to executable desktop program
if can make this in other way will be good

Comment: You should decide which DBMS you are using and tag them appropriately instead of tagging all of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with escaping table and field names in Derby and Hsqldb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121128/problems-with-escaping-table-and-field-names-in-derby-and-hsqldb)

Comment: You should create the tables without double quotes, as explained in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

If your code uses all unquoted table and column names, then your database schema should be created with unquoted names.

If you're having trouble now, then your new database was created/migrated with quoted names. Fix that, and you code will work unchanged.

Be aware that databases treats unquoted names differently, e.g. Oracle will change the names to uppercase, PostgreSQL will change the names to lowercase, and MS SQL Server will store the names as given, but will by default match them case-insensitively.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the tables without double quotes, as explained in the duplicate question